# Check if session data isset and apply error to each item

Tags: php, session

I have to do the following for a large amount of session variables, is there a way I can shorten this code to apply to all the variables rather than repeatedly writing out if(!isset($_SESSION['whatever'])) and adding the apropriate error to the errors array.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['fiat'])) {
$errors[fiat] = 'Please enter valid amount';
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['contact'])) {
$errors[contact] = 'Please enter valid contact';
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
$errors[name] = 'Please enter valid name';
}
```

I have tried some things with for loops and arrays but am really struggling even after some serious googling, so any help much appreciated. 
Thanks!

I have now made the following array but am unsure how to use it:

```
$errors = array(
    $_SESSION['fiat'] => 'Please enter valid amount',
    $_SESSION['contact'] => 'Please enter valid contact',
    $_SESSION['name'] => 'Please enter valid name',
    );
```

Do i do something like the following? Not sure what goes inbetween.

```
for(!isset($errors)){

}
```

Comment: You could have an array of `inputname => errormessage` of what you're wanting to check are set and loop around. Pretty straight forward. Out of interest, it looks like you're expecting user input, which makes me wonder why you'd be checking session data.

Comment: Okay sorry im new to loops, have made the array, but not sure quite how to do the rest. Its actually an unusual situation where the errors array has been destroyed and need to be recreated, to show to the user on another page. But security is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is the following:

```
$errors = array();

// List all session parameters and error messages you want to check here
$valuesToCheck = array(
    'fiat' => 'Please enter valid amount',
    'contact' => 'Please enter valid contact'
    // and so on...
);

// Loop through all values you want to check and validate it. if validation doesn't pass add error message to $errors array.
foreach ($valuesToCheck as $k => $v) {
     if(!isset($_SESSION[$k])) {
         $errors[$k] = $v;
     }
}

// Check if after the validation array with errors is not empty then deal with it.
if (!empty($errors)) {
    // Do something with errors here
}
```

PS: I think you should learn more about software development basics before start writing a code. This will be useful in your further career.

Comment: Ah keys and values is the fundamental part i was missing! Will try this think it will do the trick! Thank you very much don man!

Comment: Sure thing was just trying it out :)